# Failed to bypass maven checkstyle plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-checkstyle-plugin

My project is consisted of two modules, one is common, the other let's call it X.

When using maven to "clean install" module X, it complained:

```
You have 50 Checkstyle violations.
```

Looking into the pom.xml I didn't see any checkstyle maven plugin, but in the "common" module I did find it in "common"'s pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Since module X depends on module "common", I updated common's checkstyle plugin in pom.xml like this:

```
<configuration>
  <skip>true</skip>
</configuration>
```

and rebuilt the common module before I ran the "clean install" on X module.

To play safe, I added one more setting on the mvn command when running X module:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dcheckstyle.skip
```

However, it looks that neitherthe change in "common"'s pom.xml w.r.t checkstyle plugin nor the additional setting on mvn command had any effect on the running - it still complained the same.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with, `pluginManagment` and it works fine. You need to add this in your parent `pom` file.

```
<pluginManagement> 
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did add it already to the relevant pom file. It didn't work for me. However I figured it out myself - amending the plugin itself along is not sufficient, at least not in my case. I'll answer my question in a separate post.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there are two places in the pom.xml that involve checkstyle plugin: one is under the tag

```
<pluginManagement>
```

, in which I added:

```
<skip>true</skip>
```

However it's not sufficient (at least in my case), I found the checkstyle was also registered under:

```
<build><plugins>
```

it looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration> 
        <skip>true</skip>
        ....
    </configuration>
<plugin>
```

Now after I added skip being true to both places and rebuilt the project modules, the errors were gone.